# Android Get html source and slice with XPath

Tags: java, android, xpath

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import com.example.androidtablayout.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PhotosActivity extends Activity  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);

        String htmlCode = "";

        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            htmlCode += inputLine;

        in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.print("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

             XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            try {
                String str = (String) xpath.evaluate("//*[@class='postunit'][1]",htmlCode, XPathConstants.STRING);
                 TextView t = new TextView(this);
                 t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
                 t.setText(str);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    }
}
```

Hey. I wanna get html source from a website and I did it.
When I want slice with XPath, I dont get any thing on my layout screen.

I try replace TextView Code out of try catch, but it doesnt work and return this error (str is not used)

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: If you put the code setting TextView out of the try/catch, the error "str is not used" is probably a warning because you don't actually use it. What is your XPath returning?

Comment: I can't return anything. If i can take return, i get little text.

Comment: Post the html you're trying to grab/slice

Comment: Is it neccesary? I only get html source code and parse it.

Comment: The more information you can give, the easier it is to determine the problem and give a solution. Right now, if your XPath isn't returning anything/showing anything in the TextView, then I would first test your xpath out on the html myself. If that's not something you want to put up, just give a snippet or something to work with.